# Catching an error for an async call

Tags: node.js, bunyan

And then when adding a stream, I try to catch an occurring error:

```
try {
  logger.addStream(stream); // ERROR HAPPENS AT THIS CALL

  console.info(`TRY activated`);

} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

I do get the `TRY activated` message, but the app still crashes. This leads me to the thought that the async model prevents the `try-catch` to work here.

I added a callback to the `addStream()` as follows:

```
logger.addStream(stream, (err, stream) => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

but this doesn't help either.

Also tried with `logger.on('error', (err, stream) => { console.log(err) });` but unsuccessful as well.

I'm getting a `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`error:

```
/app/node_modules/gelf/gelf.js:95
       throw err;
       ^

 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND graylog-server
     at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

Can I catch that locally? F.e. without adding `uncaughtException` to my `process`, etc...

Comment: `logger.on('error', function(err) { ... })`?

Comment: Did that, too. Doesn't work.

Comment: It might help to include the error that you're seeing.

Comment: @mscdex, sorry my bad. I updated the post.

Comment: I doubt that error is being raised as a result of `logger.addStream()`. It's most likely occurring when you make the initial connection to your graylog server. So you probably need to add an `'error'` handler for your graylog connection object instead of the bunyan logger object.

Comment: Same issue here.  Any updates?